# sending packet with scapy custom ethernet header

Tags: networking, router, wireless-router, package-management, sniffing

Why sending packet with different ethernet source Mac address never reach target? Note: I used scapy sendp for sending the packet and I have my friends laptop up and connected to network?

Answer (score 0):

you should probably try with the latest version from the project's git repository (see https://github.com/secdev/scapy).

this works for me.

```
>>> x = Ether(src='01:00:0c:cc:cc:cc', dst='00:11:22:33:44:55')
>>> ls(x)
dst        : DestMACField         = '00:11:22:33:44:55' (None)
type       : XShortEnumField      = 0               (0)
>>> sendp(x, iface='eth0')
.
Sent 1 packets
```